# Definition of regular surface in do Carmo's book

Tags: differential-geometry

In the definition of do Carmo's book, he mentioned that the parametrization must be one-to-one which is to avoid self-intersection. There are two questions I am curious about it.

1) Why one-to-one implies there is no self-intersection?

2) Why do we need no self-intersection to define a regular surface?

Comment: Pretty much by definition of the term "self-intersection", this means there exist $p_1 \neq p_2$ such that $f(p_1) = f(p_2)$. No self intersection means that for all $p_1, p_2, $ if $p_1 \neq p_2$ then $f(p_1) \neq f(p_2)$; but this is precisely the definition of being one-to one. You need the no self-intersection condition, because otherwise you could have "sharp corners" of your surface. To really visualise this, go down one-dimension, and think of curves; if you allowed for self-intersection, you could construct  a curve in the plane which crossed itself at an "X", so it wouldn't be smooth

Comment: do you mean in dimension 1, at that point, there will be two tangent vectors?

Comment: that would be the informal way of saying things. strictly speaking, at that point, there is NO tangent vector (I think you have the right idea, but I hope you realise the subtle distinction I'm trying to make.. because you can't have 2 (linearly independent) tangent vectors to a 1-dimensional curve at a single point)

Comment: yes, I get what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: @peek-a-boo. Just to further confirm, this means the way we define regular surface was to ensure the existence of UNIQUE tangent plane at each point?

Comment: What do you mean unique tangent plane?

Comment: @IAmNoOne If we allow self intersection, at the point of intersection, there will be more than one tangent plane and we do not know which one to choose . Avoiding self intersection is to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Glad you cleared your own question.